# Is it possible to have an Azure DevOps project on a basic plan?

Tags: azure-devops

When I try to create a DevOps project In Azure portal

Home>DevOps Projects

When I click Add,ASP.NET Core, Web App Windows or Web App Linux

The only option for service plans is S1

The Pricing tier shows as S1 Standard
Is there any way to get a cheaper tier?  Is there even a way to share the plan. There seems to be no choice on the create screen.

[image]

Comment: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-au/services/devops/compare-features/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Click the Change button to open Settings where you can change Pricing tier.

[image]